# Expressing a conditional probability formula in words

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given a random variable $X$ and probability mass function $pmf_1$, $P(x \vert pmf_1)$ denotes the probability that the RV $X$ takes value $x$, given that the RV $X$ belongs to $pmf_1$.

How to write $P(pmf_1 \vert x)$ using similar wording as above?
It is the probability that a random variable $?$ takes the value $?$ given that we observe the point $x$.

I'm not sure what the questions marks be substituted by. I know another wording of $P(pmf_1 \vert x)$ i.e. probability that $x$ came from $pmf_1$, but what explicitly is the random variable here?

**Context:** The context I was thinking of is that of following. Suppose we have two pmfs and we want to find out which pmf the observation $x$ came from. In this context, is it possible to explicitly state what the random variable for $P(pmf_1  \vert x)$ is?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you say "random variable," you are already assuming the existence of its fixed probability mass/density function. If this is the case, then $P(X=x \mid \text{pmf})$ is redundant.

$P(\text{pmf} \mid X=x)$ is kind of weird, and starts getting into Bayesian stuff. As you noted, it is unclear what the random variable is. Perhaps I can describe an example where it does make sense.

Suppose we have a coin that might have a bias. So we know $X \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$ for some parameter $p$, but we don't know $p$. Does $p$ even have a distribution? In the Bayesian context, one "base" assumption is that $p$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, we will assume that here. Suppose we flip it $10$ times and get $7$ heads. Then the distribution for the parameter $p$, given this knowledge, can be written as $$P(p \mid \mathcal{D}=\{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0\}).$$ This is known as the [posterior distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability). The maximum likelihood estimate for $p$ can be found by noting that
$$P(p \mid \mathcal{D}) \propto P(\mathcal{D} \mid p) P(p)$$
by Bayes's rule, and then maximizing the right-hand side. It turns out that the maximum likelihood estimate is exactly the sample proportion $7/10$. [There are some issues with using the maximum likelihood; for example, if you flip two heads in a row, then the maximum likelihood estimate would be $p=1$, i.e., the coin always gives heads, which seems absurd. This can be fixed by changing what we assume the distribution of the prior $P(p)$ is, instead of being uniform.]

Comment: thanks, the context I was thinking of (but forgot to mention) is that of following. Suppose we have two pmfs and we want to find out which pmf the point x came from. so p(x|pmf1) doesn't become redundant. In this context, is it possible to explicitly state what the random variable for P(pmf1|x) is?

Comment: "In the Bayesian context, we usually assume p is uniformly distributed on [0,1]" Uniformly distributed is certainly one option but there are many others.

Comment: @user13107 See Graham's answer, sorry I was not able to respond in time.

Comment: @Did Thanks for pointing that out, edited.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathsf P(x\mid\mathrm{pmf_1})$ is read as "the probability that a random variable, $X$, takes on a value given that it belongs to a distribution with probability mass function $\mathrm{pmf_1}$", then: $\mathsf P(\mathrm{pmf_1}\mid x)$ would be read as "the probability that a random variable, $X$, belongs to a distribution with probability mass function $\mathrm{pmf_1}$ given that it takes on a value."

Here the identity of random variable is implicit from the context, not from the symbols themselves.  It's basically shorthand.

To be explicit you would write something like: $\mathsf P(X\!=\!x\mid F_X\!=\!\mathrm{pmf_1}), \mathsf P(F_X\!=\!\mathrm{pmf_1}\mid X\!=\!x)$, where $F_X$ is the probability mass function of $X$.

Or just passably: $\mathsf P_{X\mid F_X}(x\mid \mathrm{pmf_1}), \mathsf P_{F_X\mid X}(\mathrm{pmf_1}\mid x)$

It's also rather unusual notation.  What is the context?

---

> Context: The context I was thinking of is that of following. Suppose we have two pmfs and we want to find out which pmf the observation $x$ came from. In this context, is it possible to explicitly state what the random variable for $\mathsf P(\mathrm{pmf_1}\mid x)$

Well, it is possible to do this using Bayes' Theorem.

$$\mathsf P_{F_X\mid X}(\mathrm{pmf_1}\mid x) = \dfrac{\mathsf P_{X\mid F_X}(x\mid \mathrm{pmf_1})\mathsf P_{F_X}(\mathrm{pmf_1})}{\mathsf P_{X\mid F_X}(x\mid \mathrm{pmf_1})\mathsf P_{F_X}(\mathrm{pmf_1})+\mathsf P_{X\mid F_X}(x\mid \mathrm{pmf_2})\mathsf P_{F_X}(\mathrm{pmf_2})}$$

You know $\mathsf P_{X\mid F_X}(x\mid \mathrm{pmf_1})$.  It's just $\mathrm{pmf_1}(x)$.

Likewise $\mathsf P_{X\mid F_X}(x\mid \mathrm{pmf_2})=\mathrm{pmf_2}(x)$

That leaves determining the **prior probabilities** for $\mathsf P_{F_X}(\mathrm{pmf_1}), \mathsf P_{F_X}(\mathrm{pmf_2})$.   These would be the measure of certainty that $F_X$ is either function.

Comment: thanks, the context is that of following. Suppose we have two pmfs and we want to find out which pmf the point x came from.

Comment: (after your edit) I got how the derivation of p(pmf1 | x) works. So in conclusion, is Fx the random variable here?

Comment: @user13107 $F_X$ is the probability mass function of random variable $X$. As we are weighing the possibility of $F_X$ being either $\mathrm{pmf_1}$ or $\mathrm{pmf_2}$, in a sense it can be *treated* as a random variable; although it isn't random or variable; just unknown.